# KML file from importphotos plug does not display photos

Tags: qgis, photos

When I create a KML file using Importphotos I get no errors. When I open the KML file in google earth and click a point of a geolocated photo I get a pop up but it does not display the picture. The file path and everything is fine. See photo below (I whited out an area as there is sensitive information).

Does anyone have a fix for this?

[image: what is displayed when i click a point in google earth]

Comment: images files need to be in the same location of the project (e.g. *.qgz)

Comment: The photos displayed fine in QGIS but do not display when opening the KML file. Do you mean the KML file needs to be in the same folder as the photos even though the filepath to the photos are correct? I have tried moving the KML file to the same path as the photos and still get an error displaying the photos.

Comment: look up relative paths KML https://developers.google.com/kml/faq#relative-paths-in-kmz-files

Comment: I believe this will be the solution to my problem. Monday I will need to figure out how to edit the code of the plug-in. 

https://github.com/KIOS-Research/ImportPhotos/issues/105

Comment: What is your OS?  Last time I checked Debian Linux Google Earth did not support relative paths to images via a KML, only full paths were supported on Linux.